# Visual Studio 2010 Developer Edition Features

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone tell me a brief summary about the features of VSTS 2010.

I want a brief introduction on : Class Designer, Static Code Analysis, Code Profiling, Unit Testing with code coverage, Test Impact Analysis and Intellitrace.

Answer (score 1):

With some Googling:

- [Class Designer](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions)
- [Static Code Analysis](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/StaticCodeAnalysis.aspx)
- [Code Profiling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9z62c29.aspx) (Ultimate and Premium only)
- [Unit Testing with code coverage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379625%28VS.80%29.aspx) (Not 2010 per se, but could be useful)
- [Test Impact Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286598.aspx)
- [Intellitrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264915.aspx) (Ultimate only)